# Codeigniter + Nginx 404 not found

Tags: codeigniter, url, nginx, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I'm having trouble configuring Codeigniter 2 with nginx.
No problem with the landing page.
But permalinks is not found.

> 404 Not Found

nginx

Htaccess:

```
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

What should I do?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Show us code as well

Answer (score 2):

Nginx checks the case of the class loaded and the name of the file.

Ex: class name is Login. File name is login.php
Result: 404.

Change the file name to Login.php and nginx would start working as expected.

Imp Note: Class name and file name's case should match.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the `.htaccess` file is for apache servers and therefore does nothing for your nginx server. You have to configure `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file. Before that you should backup your current file `cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.backup`.

Then, try this one code:

```
# nginx configuration
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 break;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I used [this](http://winginx.com/en/htaccess) online service to get the code.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/) configuration recommended by nginx.